# What is the difference between PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS and LOADER_USAGE_STATS?

Tags: android, mobile, permissions, manifest, usage-statistics

I have been working on some Android app and I am trying to figure out the difference between the two permissions.

Reading from the Google's manifest:

1. **PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS** "Allows an application to collect component usage statistics"
   [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS)
2. **LOADER_USAGE_STATS** "Allows a data loader to read a package's access logs. The access logs contain the set of pages referenced over time. A data loader has to be the one which provides data to install an app." [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#LOADER_USAGE_STATS)

The terms "component" and "package" terms seem to be slightly vague in regards to usage statistics. What I do not understand here is what exactly they collect.

My goal: make the app ask for one of these permissions so it can gather information about users apps' usage, for instance, how much time the user was using YouTube app today etc.